# Google-Maps-for-Rails on iphone does not display a draggable map for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, gmaps4rails

The html below generates a google map. However, when I hover over the map, the cursor does not change from an arrow to a hand like the one in the jquery mobile example http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#basic_map.  I am testing on Safari under the iPhone user agent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="/assets/gmaps4rails.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="page" data-role="page">
  <header data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed"></header>  
  <div data-role="content">
     <div id="map" class="gmaps4rails_map"></div>
  </div>
  <footer data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
  </footer>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.5/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.center_latitude = "37.7668452";
Gmaps.map.map_options.center_longitude = "-122.2537803";
Gmaps.map.map_options.disableDefaultUI = true;
Gmaps.map.map_options.draggable = true;
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"title":"Test","lat":"37.7668452","lng":"-122.2537803"}];
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
</script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the code missing and/or is Google-Maps-for-Rails mobile enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google-Maps-for-Rails is mobile enabled.  The map that appears on mobile is an image and can't be dragged on a desktop safari browser.